# Update ListView with Firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-remote-config

I've a `ListView` which will have 10 list item. Each row has a `imageview`, `textview` and a `button`. I want to achieve this functionality where I can change `imageview`, `textview` and link in the `button` `onclick()` function dynamically .

I'm able to achieve the entire process with Firebase remote config. But I read somewhere that remote config shouldn't be used to update the app very often instead database should be used to change data real-time. I've no experience with Firebase database. Should I stick with remote config or use database?

I want to update listview item like in everything 12 hours

Comment: I've reworded your question because asking for recommendations/tutorials is off-topic here.

Comment: OK, that's cool man, but at least help me with that. I'm talking about programming related question after all

Comment: You could try to [edit] your question to include the code that you do have, the post that says not to use remote config, and some attempts at implementing the rest of the question you're asking. I'm not sure what you're looking for - a recommendation or an actual solution.